# Delphi - Possible to write to resources of an application withing another application?

Tags: delphi, resources, delphi-7

Just out of curiosity, do you think this is possible:
Writing to the resources of a file, stored in the resources of the same file.
Let's say we have a builder and a stub. Usually you would use the builder to write settings to the resources of another extracted file named "stub.exe".

Now I want to know, is it possible(in delphi 7) to write the settings to the resources of "stub.exe" when stored in the resources of the builder? 
Sounds better when I ask it in my head, hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resources of a file are stored in read only memory. In order to be able to write to them you would need to use `VirtualProtect` to make the memory writeable. This simple program proves the concept:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Windows, Classes;

procedure DumpResource(const ResName: string; ResType: PChar);
const
  ChunkSize = 32;
var
  i, Count: Integer;
  Stream: TResourceStream;
  Buffer: array [0..ChunkSize-1] of Byte;
  HexBuffer: array [0..2*ChunkSize-1] of Char;
  Text: string;
begin
  Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, ResType);
  try
    while Stream.Position < Stream.Size do
    begin
      Count := Min(ChunkSize, Stream.Size - Stream.Position);
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, Count);
      BinToHex(@Buffer, HexBuffer, Count);
      SetString(Text, HexBuffer, Count*2);
      Writeln(Text);
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ZeroiseResource(const ResName: string; ResType: PChar);
var
  Res: HRSRC;
  ResHandle: HGLOBAL;
  Ptr: Pointer;
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  Res := FindResource(HInstance, PChar(ResName), ResType);
  Win32Check(Res <> 0);

  ResHandle := LoadResource(HInstance, Res);
  Win32Check(ResHandle <> 0);

  Ptr := LockResource(ResHandle);
  Win32Check(Ptr <> nil);

  Win32Check(VirtualProtect(Ptr, SizeofResource(HInstance, Res), PAGE_READWRITE, 
    OldProtect));
  ZeroMemory(Ptr, SizeofResource(HInstance, Res));
  Win32Check(VirtualProtect(Ptr, SizeofResource(HInstance, Res), OldProtect, 
    OldProtect));
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  Writeln('Original resource');
  DumpResource('MAINICON', RT_GROUP_ICON);

  ZeroiseResource('MAINICON', RT_GROUP_ICON);

  Writeln('Modified resource');
  DumpResource('MAINICON', RT_GROUP_ICON);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

However, I don't think that I would take this path. I would do the following.

- Allocate memory in your builder process to hold a copy of the executable being built.
- Copy the version of the executable stored in the resource to the memory you just allocated.
- Modify the executable in that memory.
- Write the executable from memory to disk.

Note that I'm assuming in all this that your goal is to make the modifications before you save the executable to disk.

Comment: "make the modifications before you save the executable to disk"
That is correct yes. Very interesting, was just curious if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions below:

```
Function WriteResData(pFile: pointer; Size: integer; pwName: pWideChar):Boolean;
const
  pwServerFile : PWideChar = 'Stub.exe'  ;
var
  hResourceHandle: Cardinal;
begin
  hResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResourceW(pwServerFile, False);
  Result := UpdateResourceW(hResourceHandle, PWideChar(10), pwName, 0, pFile, Size);
  EndUpdateResourceW(hResourceHandle, False);
end;

procedure ResGet(ResName: pwidechar; var data : pointer; var Size:LongWord);
var
  ResSrc: Cardinal;
  ResGlobal: Cardinal;
begin
  ResSrc := FindResourceW(0, ResName, PWideChar(10));
  ResGlobal := LoadResource(0, ResSrc);
  Data := Pointer(ResGlobal);
  Size := SizeofResource(0, ResSrc);
end;
```

Perform ResGet on Builder using ParamStr(0) path, then apply WriteResData to Stub.

Source: http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicscounterstrikewireleases/func-indelphiexample

Comment: This isn't going to work here because asker is wanting to modify the resource data of a resource inside the executing process.

Comment: But you cant modify a file if its in execution?

Comment: You can't modify the file but you can change what was loaded into memory. I don't think you've quite understood what was asked.